# Azure function - output json object - Capitals change to lowercase

Tags: azure-functions

I have an azure function outputting a jsonobject.
The output is exported using this code

```
return OkObjectResult(obj)
```

The original object has capitalization in the property names
The output object has all property names as lower case
How do I define it to not change the capitalization?

Comment: I can keep the capitalization property in the json.  Did you do Deserialize? Check my [response pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GZIx.png).

Comment: Any update on this issue now?

Answer (score 3):

Cause you don't provide your code about how did you create json object, so I provide my test code. It works for me. I use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` create a json object and pass it to response.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static IActionResult Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ 'Name': 'Jon Smith', 'Address': { 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY' }, 'Age': 42 }");

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(stuff)
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }
```

And below is my result, it keeps capitalization.

[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other problem ,please feel free to let me know.